# Remove the last comma in a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a data.frame. It looks like this:

```
name    state
Lily    NY
Tom     NY,NJ,
John    PA,NJ
David   SC,PA,NY,
Jim     FL,PA
......
```

There are more than 100 rows. I just want to remove the last comma in each string if there is. My goal is not to remove all the last character.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a regular expression? Assuming your data frame is `DF`:

```
DF$state <- gsub(",$", "", DF$state)
```

The regular expression `,$` means every comma that occurs at the end of a string. The command `gsub` replaces every instance of the first argument with the second argument (in this case, nothing) that occurs in the third argument (`DF$state`).

Comment: if the case is like this 'GO:0048812, here i want to remove this symbol " ' " from the beginning which occurs before G

Answer (score 3):

With `R 3.6.0`, we can also use `trimws` with `whitespace` parameter specifying the `,`

```
DF$state <- trimws(DF$state, whitespace = ",")
DF$state
#[1] "NY"       "NY,NJ"    "PA,NJ"    "SC,PA,NY" "FL,PA"
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(name = c("Lily", "Tom", "John", "David", "Jim"
 ), state = c("NY", "NY,NJ,", "PA,NJ", "SC,PA,NY,", "FL,PA")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```